# Secure uploaded public files with application login

Tags: php, apache, security

Our client made a security request and I don't know if it's possible to do. Help me please. There is an company web app let's say "www.company.com". Users log in and upload a company related files to "www.company.com/files/user/important_document.pdf". These files are accessible for all internet if they have the url. Client requested that these files should be accessible only while the user is logged in the app. Is it possible to do? It's a PHP app on Apache 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You do it by removing the possibility to make direct URL links to the files, and having a PHP script which manages the download process. The PHP script would require a logged-in session to exist before it will do anything.

Firstly, you must store the files in a folder outside the webserver's directory so they cannot be accessed directly by a HTTP request. When a file is uploaded, keep a record of  its name and location in a database table, and give it an ID.

Then if someone wants to request a file, you can write a PHP script which gives a list of all the recorded files. Each entry would have a link to download the file, but the link would be something like `https://www.example.com/download.php?id=123`. So to download the file, the user must visit your download.php script and give the ID of the file. That script will then find the entry in the database with that ID, find the file path and return the file's contents for download (by streaming the file content and setting the appropriate HTTP headers - you can find examples of this process online in many places).

Your can download.php can of course be programmed to only allow logged-in users to visit it. If necessary you can also restrict access to files further, by having rules about which users can access which files.